# Which permissions are required in order to use geolocation in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: android, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Google Maps API v3 in my Worklight app. It works fine in when previewing it in Worklight Console, but when I try to run it in my Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0),  I am unable to get my current location. Internet is on and GPS too.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding these to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?
Try adding them and then re-build the project. You can find the file in the native folder of the Worklight app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```